# Fire 'change' event of textarea inside the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, iframe, textarea

I have a page (**index.htm**) that contains iframe (**iframe.htm**) from the same domain.

Inside the iframe there is a **textarea** element that handles its 'change' event.

There is a jquery code at the main page that changes textarea content using val(). Then I'm trying to fire the 'change' event calling to change() function.

However, this doesn't work. Value changes, but 'change' event doesn't work. This works as expected if textarea is not inside the iframe.

**QUESTION:** how to force event triggering on an element inside the iframe?

**iframe.htm:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("textarea").bind("change", function () {
            alert("changed"); });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.htm:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").bind("click", function () {
            var frame = document.getElementById("frame");
            var txt = frame.contentDocument.getElementById("txt");
            $(txt).val("hello").change();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="frame" src="iframe.htm"></iframe>
    <button id="btn">Fire change</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using .trigger('change') instead of .change()

Comment: change() does exactly the same, it's just a shortcut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this.
Problem is that using iframe we have different instance of jQuery inside. To fire the event, one should refer to that iframe-nested jQuery instance instead of the parent one.

So instead of

```
$(txt).val("hello").change();
```

simply use

```
frame.contentWindow.$(txt).val("hello").change();
```

Hope this will help to someone. I've spent few hours looking for the reason of this bug:)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    $iframe = $('#iframe').contents().find('#txt');

    $iframe.on('change',function(){
      var val = $(this).val();
      console.log(val);
    });

   $('#btn').click(function(){
      $iframe.trigger('change');
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, this should also work, but actual logic of my application is more difficult and prevents me from doing this way. Please take a look at my own answer. Can't vote yours up, have no rep:)